# React 18 doesn't support redux-toolkit or other libraries yet?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I updated my app to React v18, and there's an error when installing styled-components and redux-toolkit. React v18 doesn't support these libraries? Or did I install something wrong?

[image]

here is my dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "react": "^18.0.0-rc.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0-rc.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.0-beta.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

add to the command --force or --legacy-peer-deps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I edited my package.json file dependencies
from

```
"next": "12.1.2",
"react": "18.0.0",
"react-dom": "18.0.0"
```

to

```
"next": "10.2.0",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2"
```

then run *npm i*
It's working, **for now**, until redux-toolkit supports react18

Comment: This is not a solution

Comment: You are downgrading the React version to 17. Not the solution

Answer (score -1):

My problem is the same when i install new project using react 18

Comment: This could be added as a comment, yes i know it you need 50 points to have a comment...https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask here is a link on how to ask good question

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31410227)